# ajax Opera and Chrome bug

Tags: xml, ajax, google-chrome, opera

I have the following method, but it doesn't work in Opera and Google Chrome. I need to read xml file offline on CD. How can I fix this?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "items.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {

            $(xml).find('item').each(function(){

                var id = $(this).find('id').text();
                var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                var alcohol = $(this).find('alcohol').text();
                var volume = $(this).find('volume').text();
                $('<div class="items" id="link_'+id+'"></div>').html('<a href="files/'+name+'">'+name+'</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
            });

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code there is fine although it could be optimized a bit. It works flawlessly in every browser I've tested.

http://jsfiddle.net/SgUKY/

I believe the source of the issue is the XML content. Check your XML data against a validator perhaps?

To better answer this, I really need more information.

- Can you paste the XML here?
- What version of Opera/Chrome are you testing against?

Comment: Opera 12.02, Google Chrome 22.0.1229.94m

Comment: What's not working exactly? Can you provide any additional details?

I added your XML to my test and it still works.

http://jsfiddle.net/SgUKY/1/

Comment: Your example working good. But I try this code http://jsfiddle.net/SejberCze/qaKAB/ javascript alert only 'A' not 'B'. Problam should by in ajax.

Comment: Look in the error console. Your example is throwing a 404.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/SejberCze/qaKAB/show/items.xml does not exist.

Open Dragonfly (Opera) and Web Inspector (Chrome) and see if those browsers are throwing errors.